# What exactly does R CMD Sweave --pdf do?

Tags: r, sweave

I noticed this in the changes of R 2.14:

> R CMD Sweave now has a --pdf option to produce a PDF version of the processed Sweave document.

Trying it out, I noticed that it not only ran pdfLaTeX on the resulting tex but also correctly included bibTeX references and cleaned up afterwards. Seems like a very very nice way of using Sweave now (not to mention how easy it now is to implement the whole routine in editors).

But what exactly is this now running? I couldn't find any more details on it. It seems Sweave -> pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex at least?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for the question. I had wondered myself about the code behind that 'automagical' process.

`R CMD Sweave --pdf` ultimately calls `tools::texi2dvi`, which:

> Run[s] latex and bibtex until all cross-references are resolved and
>   create[s] either a dvi or PDF file.

[(See here for more `texi2dvi` details)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/tools/html/texi2dvi.html).

Here is the chain of events set into motion by an `R CMD Sweave --pdf` call:

- The source file `rcmdfn.c` has code that instructs `R CMD Sweave` to run `utils:::.Sweave() --args"` through `Rterm.exe`.
- If `--pdf` is set, `utils:::.Sweave()` calls `tools::texi2pdf()` to process the Sweave file.
- `texi2pdf()` in turn calls `tools::texi2dvi()`.
- Finally, `texi2dvi()` looks at the environment to learn which tools are available to it, and does the work described in the help file linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to perform the conversion from Rnw to pdf manually en see how many times the respective steps are needed to get the same result as R CMD Sweave.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the interior workings, but I know the development version of RStudio will let you select between `knitr` and `Sweave` as well as between `pdflatex` and `xelatex`, and gives `bibtex` as an option.